# How to capture group with optional number of letters/numbers followed by optional comma?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm altering the segment of a string in javascript and got the following working (first iteration -optional comma).

```
var foo = "wat:a,username:x,super:man"
foo.replace(/(username\:\w+)(?:,)*/,"go:home,");
//"wat:a,go:home,super:man"
```

The trick now is that I might actually replace a key/value with only the key ... so I need to capture the original group with both optional value + optional comma.

```
var foo = "wat:a,username:,super:man"
foo.replace(/ ????? /,"go:home,");
//"wat:a,go:home,super:man"
```

As a bonus I'd like the most concise way to capture both optional numbers/and letters (updating my original to also support)

```
var foo = "wat:a,username:999,super:man"
foo.replace(/ ????? /,"go:home,");
//"wat:a,go:home,super:man"
```

Comment: Replace `\w+` with `\w*`.

Comment: What exactly do you want to match ?

Comment: Not sure if I should post it now...

Comment: @stribizhev didn't see you comment. Feel free to post your answer, I can update mine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to replace the `+` (1 or more occurrences of the preceding subpattern) quantifier with the `*` (0 or more occurrences of the preceding subpattern).

See [*Quantifier Cheatsheet* at rexegg.com](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#cheat_sheet):

> `A+`   **One or more** `A`s, as many as possible (greedy), giving up characters if the engine needs to backtrack (docile)
>
> `A*`   **Zero** or more `A`s, as many as possible (greedy), giving up characters if the engine needs to backtrack (docile)

Besides, you are not using any of the capturing groups defined in the pattern, so I suggest removing them.

```
.replace(/username:\w*,*/,"go:home,")
                     ^
```

And if you have just 1 optional `,`, use just the `?` quantifier (1 or 0 repetition of the preceding subpattern):

```
.replace(/username:\w*,?/,"go:home,")
                       ^
```

Note that in case you can have any characters before the end of string or comma, you can also use Fede's suggestion of using a negated character class: `/username:[^,]*,*/`. The `[^,]*` matches any character (even a newline) other than a comma.

Also, please note that you do not need to escape a colon. The characters that must be escaped outside of character class to be treated as literals are `.`, `*`, `+`, `?`, `^`, `$`, `{`, `(`, `)`, `|`, `[`, `]`, `\`. See [RegExp MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).

Comment: thank you 100x -seriously this was by far the most anyone has paid it forward :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understood your question, but if you want to match `username:??` you can use below regex:

```
(username\:\w*)
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/lL1yZ7/1)**

[image]

**Update**: As **[stribizhev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3832970/stribizhev)**, pointed in his comment `\w*` can do the trick, however if you want to extend the regex to any characters besides letters or numbers you can use:

```
(username\:[^,]*)
```